# Run function when resize finished (without underscope.js)?

Tags: angularjs

From controller i detect resize event for $window and restart my carousel directive after it .

But the problem is , that carusel restart nearly 5-6 times . I cant find any helpful solution about this .

```
angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {                                
    $scope.$apply(function(){
          $scope.showCarousel = false;      
          $timeout(function(){
             $scope.calculateGamesCount();
             $scope.showCarousel = true; 
          }, 250);              
    });
});
```

How can i detect , if resize event is finished then run functions ?

Comment: search for debouncing functions

Comment: I find debouncing way , but its include lodash.js . I dont want to add new library just for one solution )

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no such event as "resize done" that we can hook into. Each pixel change is its own independent event. If a third party solution is 100% out of the question, you could implement your own home-grown debounce:

```
function debounce(f, n){
    let allow_run = true;
    return function(...args){
        if(allow_run){
            allow_run = false;
            setTimeout(_=> allow_run = true, n);
            return f.apply(f, args);
        }
    }
}

window.onresize = debounce(_=> console.log('resizing!'), 250);
```

Essentially, we have a gatekeeper, `allow_run`. If the debounced function is called while the gate is "open", execution is allowed, and the gate is closed until the timeout (`n` milliseconds) expires. If the debounced function is called with the gate "closed", nothing happens.

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ecf7ju0b/)